# How can I get the clicked pin on an iPhone map?

Tags: iphone, dictionary, touch

So, I have a map with many annotations on it, each pin has it's own coordination and name and description, but I don't want to show it once the user clicks on the pin. How can I get the selected pin and it's data (name, coordination & description) after it got clicked?

Comment: whats wrong with the delegate? is google down? ;)

Answer (score 1):

implement the mkmapviewdelegate

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view`

Comment: I actually implemented - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view and
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view but they never get called. I put NSLog in these two functions and clicked on the pin but they never get called. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Have you set the mapviw's delegate correctly?

Comment: Have you set the mapviw's delegate correctly?

Comment: Yes, I did. Actually I just figured what the problem is. I put address and title of annotations blank, that's why it wont run the mapView:didSelectAnnotationView. But the problem is I don't want to show the pop up dialog once you click on the pin, I just wanna have the title and address without showing it. What should I do?